# Spark Dataframe handling duplicated name while joining using generic method

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, ambiguous

There are two dataframes

```
Data1 = [("1",None,"a","Kelvin"), \
        ("2","1","b","Ho"), \
        ("2","2","b","Ho"), \
        ("7","1","c","Shuai"), \
    
      ]
col1= ["ID","s_name","group","name"]
tableA = spark.createDataFrame(data = Data1, schema = col1)
    
Data2 = [("1","1","bird"), \
        ("2",None,"tiger"), \
      ]
col2= ["ID","s_name","classes"]
tableB = spark.createDataFrame(data = Data2, schema = col2)
```

When they are joined together, `tableA.join(tableB,["ID"],"left")`
the columns of the new dataframe are:
['ID', 's_name', 'group', 'name', 's_name', 'classes']

Since tableA contains tableB, the key column in tableB is redundant and ambiguous if we want to coalesce joined dataframe later so I can use

```
tableB = tableB.withColumnRenamed("s_name","s_name_2")
```

then after join, I apply drop

```
val = "s_name"
tableA.join(tableB,["ID"],"left").withColumn(val,coalesce(col(val),col(val+"_2"))).drop(val+"_2")
```

The problem with this approach is if I want to use generic variable to handle all ambiguous name cases:
for instance the column headers with same name is stored in a list called `ambiguous_name`
then I do

```
for val in ambiguous_name:
  tableB = tableB.withColumnRenamed(val,val+"_2")
```

then drop the ambiguous column using

```
joined_table = tableA.join(tableB,["ID"],"left").drop("key_2")
for val in ambiguous_name:
  joined_table = joined_table.drop(val+"_2")
```

But, tableB looks something like this:

```
Data2 = [("1","1","test","bird"), \
        ("2",None,"test2","tiger"), \
      ]
col2= ["ID","s_name","s_name_2","classes"]
tableB = spark.createDataFrame(data = Data2, schema = col2)
```

Of course I can call it `tableB = tableB.withColumnRenamed(val,val+"_3")`
but what happen if `col2= ["ID","s_name","s_name_3","classes"]` ?

Is there a generic postfix naming to resolve this?

Comment: Instead of joining on `ID` you can join on the common columns between both dataframes.

Comment: thanks. but ID is the only column I want to join. The situation is more complex than the above example.
For instance the key column in tableA I am going to do certain manipulation with it then at the end , I am going to coalesce key in transformed_tableA and key in tableB after they joined.

Comment: Please update your question with a more relevant example.

Comment: thanks. I modified my question to reflect and chang the column header name "key" to "s_name" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, the issue you have can be resolved in away using alias.

```
new = tableA.alias('tableA').join(tableB.alias('tableB'),["ID"],"left")

new = new.withColumnRenamed('tableB.key','tableB.key'+"_3").show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use more generic way to handle it, for instance instead of calling it tableB.key, I want to use a generic variable. With the renaming strategy, I am not constrained by the existing column name.
If the existing column name is key_3, and I use variable+"_3" to handle, it is ambiguous with existing key_3 column.

Comment: But if you rename the ambiguous columns the same way don't they remain ambiguous? Maybe also share why you prefer a unanimous rename. understanding that inform options

Comment: thanks. I modified my question to reflect and chang the column header name "key" to "s_name" to avoid confusion.